# allocating memory for structure via double pointer

Tags: c, data-structures, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

HI I need help in allocating memory for a structure which is part of 2nd structure and 2nd structure is having double pointer as deceleration.

```
struct ant{ 
    int stu;
    int clas;
    char *name;
};

struct cat{
    int a;
    int b;
    struct ant *c;
};

int main()
{
   struct cat **sample;
   struct ant *info;

   info = calloc(1, sizeof(*info));

   <here i had allocated memory for **info** which is of type **ant**>
   <now i need to assig this **info** to the pointer which is there in **cat** structure>
   <how we can achive this> ?
}
```

Comment: How many cats and ants do you want to play with?

Comment: what does it actually mean

Comment: How can i know for how ants should one allocate the memory when initializing a cat?

Comment: ants should be one

Answer (score 0):

Your `cat` struct has a member `c` that can hold a pointer to an `ant` struct.
Just assign the pointer to your `ant` struct to the `c` member.
If you have a double pointer to a `cat` struct, you first have to dereference it.

```
struct cat *some_cat_p;
some_cat_p = calloc(1, sizeof(*some_cat_p));

struct cat **some_cat_pp;
some_cat_pp = &some_cat_p;

struct ant *some_ant_p;
some_ant_p = calloc(1, sizeof(*some_ant_p));


(*some_cat_pp)->c = some_ant_p;
```

Note: You may also want to check the return value of calloc and friends, it may return `NULL` if it fails to allocate memory.

Comment: yes we can do this but i need some_cat should be double pointer

Comment: struct cat **some_cat

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: is there no need of allocating memory for some_cat_pp

Comment: there is no additional memory allocated for some_cat_pp

Comment: How to assign the data to some_ant_p via some_cat_pp and print the same via some_cat_pp